# My sculpt tools are doing opposite of what they're supposed to

Tags: sculpting

I clicked on 'Inflate' tool and made sure I was on + and not -. Yet, my tool seems to be removing the mesh (is that the right term?) instead of adding it.

[image]

I was experimenting with a few things (including 'dyntopo') but as far as I remember, I went back to my original settings.

edit: it took me a few times to get it right but the solution given by @Blunder seems to work.

Comment: have you checked the face orientation of the mesh? There might be flipped normals then inflate has the opposite effect. You can check it with the overlays

Comment: yea, it sounds like a problem with your normals, to reset normals, select an object, and in edit mode, hit shift+n on your keyboard